# Reset GUI values in Python 2

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following code, showing the segments that my question is related to. The program executes as expected for the first time when I run. The program gets user selected inputs from the user from a GUI. After the first run, I need to reset all the values and variables to their original status without shutting down the program and re-run.  Specifically, the variable SaveFileName, is the variable that holds the file name from a PyQt LineEdit box and does not reset, even when the run button is again pressed (connected to the Run function shown below).

Is there an easy way to implement the reset in a short command? I know I can reset every value individually by putting a reset button and restore all the values to original one by one in the code, but I am looking for a simpler way if there is one. Any help is appreciated.

```
    def Run(self):
        global SaveFileName           
        SaveFileName==0

    .......other codes creating and exporting data to excel based on 
     user selected options through a GUI

        writer.save()

        if SaveFileName==0:
            self.Output_File_Window.setText("")
        if SaveFileName!=0: 
            shutil.move(path_refs + "/TEMP_file.xlsx", SaveFileName) 

        SaveFileName=str(self.Output_File_Window.text())
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to ask people to sift through. Can you reduce it to the minimal amount required to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Yes, I agree, I changed it to the few relevant lines. Thanks